# Android drawable folder for <3.2 devices

Tags: android, drawable

I have a background image of different sizes, 240x320, 320x480, 480x800, 1024x600, 1280x720. I have a drawable-large-mdpi folder that holds 480x800 image, which I use in layout-large and it seems to fit well for screens 5.1", 5.4". From my understanding, layout-large is for screens ranging from 5.1" to 7.3". My question is how to provide a different image of dimension 1024x600 for 7" tablet? Which drawable folder holds this(1024x600) image that i can make use of for 7" tablets?

How could I store 480x800, 1024x600 images in the same folder with same name so that the former can be used on 5.1", 5.4" devices and the later for 7" tablets?

In Eclipse, AVD manager Device Definitions, 5.1", 5.4", 7" devices are specified as Large mdpi. Can i place 1024x600 image in drawable-large-mdpi folder that might scale down for 5.1" and 5.4" devices?

Please help me out. I'm pretty much confused about it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 7 inch tablerts you can use

```
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)
```

Comment: Hi Onur, from which drawable folder does a 5.1", 5.4" device gets resources?

Comment: as far as i know `res/drawable-large-mdpi/` is for 5-10 inch all tablets but, you can use according to width of 5.1 and 5.4 like `layout-sw360dp` which means smallest width 360 so the tablets who has width equal or greater than 360 will use this folder, hence you can learn the width of that tablets and can create a folder like this=> `drawable-sw[your-width]dp`

Comment: What if i have a 5.1" and 7" devices of version 2.3.6, then how do i store the background image?

Comment: you can't, because 5.1 devices is produces very new so high probably they have 3.0+, and for 7', which is tablet, there is no tablet below 3.0, because tablet versions start from 3.0 honeycomb

Comment: insteresting, actually it should be an exception because tablets starts from 3.0 and above in mostly, but for those exceptions you can put files in a drawable folder with no prefix or suffix just name folder as drawable and then scale it in your code,